# iPhone Web App - Session & Current url lost when call answered

Tags: iphone, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have a multi-page website that is designed to work as a web-app on an iPhone.

It has the usual:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/images/startup.png" />
```

The site doesn't use Sencha or Javascript to navigate between pages, just standard anchor links, and page-reloads (I'm aware that the standard approach to web-apps is to use a Sencha-like interface).

It works perfectly fine when launched from the iPhone homescreen, and works the same as when viewed through Safari.

An issue seems to arise, though, when a phone call is answered mid-session.

Once the call is complete, the iPhone (version 4 in this case) reverts back to the web-app, but instead of restoring the previously-viewed page it reloads the homescreen (the same page that is loaded when the web-app is initiated)

**When viewing the site in Safari, and accepting a call, it doesn't do this and maintains the url and current session values.**

Is this a known issue in web-apps? Is there a workaround?

(one idea I have is to maintain the session and url values in a local SQLite database, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach)

Comment: I googled a bit because I was interested in the topic. It seems like it is a limitation of web apps on iPhone and you'll have to code around it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet, but Will0's answer below might work

Comment: Just changed username; Peter is referring to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to do this:

```
// Start or resume session
session_start(); 

// Extend cookie life time by an amount of your liking
$cookieLifetime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // A year in seconds
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$cookieLifetime);
```

I tested this to work on iOS 4.2.1, 5.1.1, 6.0 and 6.1. The session is even restored after turning off and restarting the device.

For a more elaborate discussion of this strategy you can take a look at my answer of this question: 
[Maintain PHP Session in web app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998900/maintain-php-session-in-web-app-on-iphone/14594908#14594908)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the login info in a $_SESSION variable, store it in a $_COOKIE. The cookie will be saved depending on when you set it to expire. As long as they log in "inside" the web app, or the regular web version (and the cookie is the same) they will not have to log in every time or when switching between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I haved the same problem with my WebApp under iOS v10. It was not a problem of session and / or cookie (session mecanism was OK, based on a cookie with suffisant lifetime).

The problem is when running in WebApp mode (i.e. application launch from a desktop shortcut, not whithin Safari), the "context" is lost when switching to another app (for example answer a call). When you come back to the app, the requested URL is not the last one, but it is the URL saved into the desktop shortcut...

In my case, the shortcut was made from the login screen , so every time I switched back to my app from another app, it was the /login URL called... It looks like I was logged out...

So be careful of the URL shortcut on your web app.
At this point, I have not found a way to specify a specific URL when the user create the shortcut.