# Get UIWebView's Session Key

Tags: ios, uiwebview, session-cookies

I'm using UIWebView in my application to show some webpages,
the thing is I can't able to fetch the session key of webpage which has been displayed
is there any way to fetch the SESSION key in web view programatically.

Comment: In UIWebView you should use cookie enstead

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148376/ipad-iphone-how-to-keep-the-session-in-a-web-app][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148376/ipad-iphone-how-to-keep-the-session-in-a-web-app

Comment: @Injectios the problem is i want to fetch the session key and display it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998900/maintain-php-session-in-web-app-on-iphone/14594908#14594908